# Coffee and orange juice concentrations with a twist

Tags: everyday-chemistry, concentration

This question dates back to a time where I used to watch something called The Curiosity Show... Kinda like Bill Nye the Science Guy's show. I just can't recall the answer to this so I'm hoping that someone could shed some light.

I have two glasses of equal size and volume, with equivalent volumes of orange juice and coffee, one beverage in each glass.

Given that I have a hypothetical non-stick, hydrophobic teaspoon on me, if I was to get my teaspoon and take a level teaspoon of coffee out of the coffee glass and put it in the glass of orange juice, give it a stir, and then get a level teaspoon of this orange juice plus coffee mix and put this teaspoon of liquid in the coffee glass and give it a stir... Do I now:

1. have more orange juice in the coffee glass than coffee in the orange juice glass;
2. have more coffee in the orange juice glass than orange juice in the coffee glass; or
3. have equal amounts of coffee in the orange juice glass and orange juice in the coffee glass?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a chemistry question.

Comment: @CurtF. I'm dealing with concentrations here... In such a situation where equal samples are taken out and switched in a certain order, how are concentrations affected? I could have done this with equal concentrations of two inert solutions. Would you have voted to close it then?

Comment: This problem is identical to the water/wine problem (asked [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33579/wine-water-mixing-problem)), which while it is a fascinating problem, the answer requires more logic than chemistry.